# Add subviews with a for loop is not showing images until loop ends

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to add subviews but all the added subviews only shows when the for loop ends, I want to know if there is a way to make appear each subview when is already added, this is my code

```
    for colum in 0 ... colums-1 {
        xPos = colum * seatWidth
        for row in 0 ... rows-1 {
            yPos = row * seatWidth

            let seatImageView = dataSource?.seatsView(sender: self, seatImageViewForRow: row, andColum: colum)
            if seatImageView?.state != .empty {
                seatImageView?.delegate = self
                seatImageView!.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: seatWidth, height: seatWidth)

                containerView?.addSubview(seatImageView!)
            }
        }
        xPos = 0
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify. As written, all of the views will appear all together very quickly after the loop is complete. What exactly do you want to happen instead? Do you want each to appear one at a time with some delay in between each one?

Comment: This would be something of a performance hog, but since you need to do this in the main thread, you can add a view.layoutIfNeeded() call after the view.addSubview(). (I'm **not** recommending this, just saying it should work.)

Comment: I want to show each view added in the screen after each addSubview inside the for loop, I tried to call setNeedsDisplay() and doesn't work, I don't believe layoutIfNeeded do the work, because there is no constraints in the added views

Answer (score 1):

if you add `Runloop.main.run(until: Date.distantPast)` directly after adding the view. The UI won't be updated until the next runloop normally, and adding this code will make sure it runs once, so it's updated.

Comment: :( this doesn't work, I guess all the views appear quickly but then is like they are added again; I want to show each view at the same time the addSubview code executes inside the for loop